# What is it that I look for?

Tags: riddle

**What is it that I look for?**

> To many, it is most important.
>
> To some, it is how they confirm.
>
> To itself, it is about one fifth.
>
> Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

Hint #1

> It is the one.

Hint #2

> It is a piece of history, lost in time, not confined to the past, present, or future.

Hint #3

> It and the fifth I speak of are actual numbers.

```
note: thanks to Rubio who helped me with this one :)
```

Comment: Before anyone asks: the note is not relevant for the riddle.

Comment: In the contrary, the `note` is very helpful: I could just ask Rubio for the answer.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Good idea. Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: @Rubio So.... might as well try... what’s the answer? :P

Comment: @thecoder16  No, **what**'s not the answer. ;)

Comment: @Rubio No, I asked you! If I asked you to write the answer on a sheet or paper, you would write what? :P

Comment: @Rubio Also, who made the puzzle? xD

Comment: After reading all the answers I feel like this riddle has lots of 'valid' answers that make sense with all the statements xD (some even more then the actual intended answer)

Comment: That's right, the creativity is amazing. How would you change the riddle so that only the right one is really valid?

Comment: @Tweakimp I don't know xD something about imagining my strenght or something xD I'm not that good with riddes anyway

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What is it that I look for?

> The letter **I**. Some of the clues refer to homophones of this letter.

To many, it is most important.

> To many, the eye is the most important sense organ. And "I", that is one's ego, is important to many, too.

To some, it is how they confirm.

> "Aye" is a onfirmation.

To itself, it is about one fifth.

> "I to itself", or *i* to the power of *i*, where *i* is the imaginary unit yields:
>
>    *iⁱ* = exp(*i*² *π* / 2) exp(−*π* / 2) ≈ 0.20788
>
>  — or about 1/5. Thanks, Sabre, for the leg up and Tweakimp for the "celebrity hint". `:)`

Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

> Saying "I" would give the answer.

Hint 1: It is the one.

> I is he Roman numeral for one and in some styles of handwriting it is also how an Arabic one is written.

Hint 2: It is a piece of history, lost in time, not confined to the past, present, or future.

> I is in "history" and "time", but not in "past", "present" or "future".

Comment: Correct! Except spoiler #4... What else can i stand for?

Comment: It seems to me that this is still clearly present in time, not lost...

Comment: it is a piece of "lost in time". i is in that string

Comment: @Tweakimp: Thanks. As for clue #4, I'm a bit at a loss, though. (When I still thought the answer was "eye", I though the 4th clue would be a homophone clue, too.)

Comment: @MOehm Ill add another Hint, just for your :)

Comment: I'm flattered. (And probably a bit thick.) `:)`

Comment: Clue number four is literal "to itself" as in "i to the i power". `i^i ≈ 0.2079 ≈ 1/5`

Comment: @Sabre: Excellent! That must be it, I imagine. (Ahem.)

Comment: :D well played! Do you have any tips how to rephrase the riddle so there arent this many hits necessary?

Comment: Amusingly, if perhaps irrelevant, "i" is exactly one fifth of "fifth" itself.

Answer (score 15):

Lolgast's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58192/4450) led me to believe the answer is:

> The green checkmark on Puzzling.SE, meaning that an answer has been accepted as the correct solution to a puzzle.

To many, it is most important.

> People here on Puzzling.SE want the checkmark on their answer because it means they solved the puzzle correctly.

To some, it is how they confirm.

> The poster of a puzzle confirms that an answer is correct by accepting it with the checkmark.

To itself, it is about one fifth.

> Accepting an answer on SE is worth 2 points, which is one-fifth the point value of upvoting an answer (10 points).

Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

> That's what you do by accepting an answer, you are telling everyone that is the correct answer.

Comment: Your explanation fits surpringly well, especially in spoiler #4, but I meant something else, sorry :)

Comment: @Tweakimp You will keep on meaning something else, most of the above answers fits your question.

Comment: I will add hints now.

Answer (score 6):

It is perhaps

> Thumbs up gesture (translates to up-vote / accept / like / confirm / appreciate etc.) 
>  [image]

As,

To many, it is most important.

> Many feel it is important to get thumbs-up for their posts on social media, nowadays.

To some, it is how they confirm.

> Thumbs-up is a gesture to confirm/acknowledge

To itself, it is about one fifth.

> It is one of the five fingers of one's hand

Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

> Not sure of this part though ! :-)

Comment: No, sorry. But it's so interesting to see what you guys come up with.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I could be on a completely wrong track here, but I'll guess:

> An upvote?

I'll do some better formatting once I'm on a pc rather than mobile, but my explanation:

To many, it's most important:

> Upvotes give some very important[citation needed] InternetPoints.

To some, it is how they confirm:

> Upvotes are a measure of how good your question is, which could be seen as a confirmation by some.

To itself, it's about one fifth:

> Bit of a stretch here, but 1 upvote on a question gives 5 reputation.

Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

> Not sure if this was also intended as a "literal" hint, but I don't really have an explanation for this one.

Comment: This answer also fits the title

Comment: No, sorry, I'm looking for something else. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to guess that what you look for is:

> **Air / oxygen**

To many, it is most important.

> We need it to live

To some, it is how they confirm.

> You can check for a person's breath to know they're alive

To itself, it is about one fifth.

> The oxygen content in air is about 21% (i.e. about a fifth)

Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

> Talking uses air

Comment: We all need it to live, not just many. Sorry :)

Comment: Heh, yeah, that's a glaring weak point in my answer!

Comment: @Tweakimp If by “all” you mean “anything that’s alive,” then no, not all species require oxygen, but many do.

Comment: I meant all humans.

Comment: @Tweakimp Anerobic bacteria: yuck

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is

> the answer

Since,

To many, it is most important.

> An answer is.

To some, it is how they confirm.

> Many confirm with a nod, some confirm with an answer.

To itself, it is about one fifth.

> You defined four statements, the answer is the fifth statement and therefore one fifth of all statements.

Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.

> If you tell us the fifth statement by yourself, it must already be the answer. Otherwise the third statement would be wrong.

Comment: I thought of this, but stumbled at explaining the 'one fifth'. Nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> the sense of sight ?

*To many, it is most important.*

> Many people's most valued sense is that of sight.

*To some, it is how they confirm.*

> Musicians who play by ear might check with notes on paper, for example; or when you when you hear a strange noise, you have a look around.

*To itself, it is about one fifth.*

> It is one of five traditional senses, but you can say there are at least a few more ([BBC article which discusses others](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20141118-how-many-senses-do-you-have)).

*Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.*

> Well, that depends what you tell us I suppose...

As for the title: *What is it that I look for?*

> Possibly the answer to this riddle: **the sense of sight.**

Comment: I had also considered this and thought that some of the lines were homophones of "eye": "aye" confirms; saying "I" gives the answer and "I" is one fifth of "sight",although that's a stretch. This would also fit the hint, because I is a Roman one.

Comment: @MOehm has pretty good points...

Comment: Oh excellent interpretation @MOehm - that sounds like an answer waiting to be written.

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned in the answers above.

The title
"What is it that I look for?"
Feel like it is also part of the riddle.

> When you ask a question you are looking for an answer which you can "checkmark"

Comment: It is, but not in the way you think it is :p

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The letter "Y" ?

*To many, it is most important.*

> "Y" is important to the word many, which would be another word without it. It could also be that "why ?" is the most important question we always ask ourselves.

*To some, it is how they confirm.*

> In most command line interfaces, you have enter "y" to validate some command (like in "are you sure to delete this folder ? y/n")

*To itself, it is about one fifth.*

> This one is tough and is my biggest concern concerning this answer. I'd say that the space between the two upper "sticks" of the capital letter "Y" could represent about a fifth of a circle diagram.

*Telling you any more, I would just be giving you the answer.*

> "Telling a(n) Y more" would indeed gives the answer !

*It is the one.*

> "Y" is one letter only.

Comment: Reading @M Oehm comment on @pb8330's answer, I have a feeling that the correct letter is instead "I", but I won't steal this answer ;)

Comment: sry, but thats not it :)